# CORS and routing issue, backend fails to serve API to itself (Node/Express)

Tags: vue.js, express, axios, cors

Summary:

I have a web app with two main components: a frontend built using Vue.js, and a backend using Express.js.

The backend serves two functions:

1. It acts as an API server for data requests and operations.
2. It also serves the Vue.js frontend's static files.

Currently, I'm facing a CORS issue where the frontend on my local machine can connect to the API successfully, but when attempting to access the office list API from the backend on the same local machine, I encounter errors.

This problem seems to arise specifically when the backend attempts to communicate with itself to serve the office list API.

---

For my application, I'm using Node/Express on the backend, Vue.js for the front-end and Heroku for production/database.

Part of my API setup is to fetch a list of Offices from my database.

Local machine set up:

- Frontend: Port 8080
- Backend: Port 3000

Both servers are running locally successfully, as well as connected to the database. The backend serves the front-end as was recommended to me prior.

However, when i use the frontend port on my local machine, i can access the office list api without issue, but on the backend server, it just won't work (same for production env, but that's another issue)

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
> the remote resource at https://app-name.herokuapp.com/api/offices.
> (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status
> code: 200.

I've [linked](https://pastebin.com/njXUicXR) the longer 'Error, cannot fetch office list' message.

As far as i know, CORS is only handled in the backend, for both frontend and backend server instances.

Here is the relevant CORS code in my server.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');
require('dotenv').config();
const morgan = require('morgan');

const app = express();

const corsOptions = {
  origin: '*',
  methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
  allowedHeaders: 'Content-Type,Authorization',
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
```

So my question is, **how can i resolve the CORS error and correctly fetch the office list from the API?**

And secondarily, why is my frontend working correctly, but my backend is not able to interact with the api?

---

APIs are naturally handled through the backend using port 3000, so curl commands are working correctly, it's the browser that is not interacting with the API correctly.

As in:

`curl http://localhost:3000/api/offices`

Displays the correct list of offices, but

`http://localhost:3000/offices`

Doesn't display any of them, even though the routes are set up properly, and the frontend

`http://localhost:8080/offices`

Does display them correctly.

I have tried:

- Changing the CORS commands, either removing them, or adding different origins and headers.
- Changing the main.js file which serves the frontend from the backend.

main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import router from './router';
import axios from 'axios';

const app = createApp(App);

const isLocal = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'; // Check if it's a local development environment

// Define the base API URL conditionally
const BASE_API_URL = isLocal
  ? 'http://localhost:3000/api/' // Local development URL
  : process.env.VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL; // Heroku-deployed URL

// Set the Axios default base URL
axios.defaults.baseURL = BASE_API_URL;

// Use the app variable you've already created
app.use(router).mount('#app');
```

- changing the env set up (I don't see how this would make a difference)

---

Requested code snippets:

The rest of the server.js (for office API routes)

```
// Import route modules for each resource
const officesRoutes = require('./routes/officesRoutes');

// API routes should be defined before static file serving
app.use('/api/offices', officesRoutes);

// Serve static files for non-API routes
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../frontend/dist')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  if (!req.path.startsWith('/api/')) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../frontend/dist/index.html'));
  }
});

// Add Debugging Statements
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(`Incoming Request: ${req.method} ${req.url}`);
  next();
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

officeRoutes.js (relevant snippet)

```
// Logging to indicate this router is being accessed
console.log("Accessing Office API router...");

// Endpoints for operations on the collection of offices
router.route('/')
    .get(async (req, res) => {
         // Fetch and return all offices
        try {
            const allOffices = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM offices');
            res.json(allOffices.rows);
        } catch (err) {
            res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
        }
    })
```

Front end /office/ snippet (router, index.js)

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';
import Home from '../views/HomePage.vue';
import OfficeList from '../views/OfficeList.vue';

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: '/offices',
    name: 'Offices',
    component: OfficeList,
  },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory('/'),
  routes
});

export default router;
```

Comment: It’s very confusing what you mean by “frontend” and “backend”. Frontend = Vue, backend = Express, no‽ How does the backend not communicate with itself‽

Comment: backend is used both the serve the frontend and the API.

You can have a backend router as an API, then serve the frontend ie. static files for non-API routes.

Comment: Which is still just the frontend, but served from the same server. You might want to clarify that.

Comment: I've added a summary for clarity. Hope that helps.

Comment: Can you include the code for how you define your routes (at least `/api`, `/api/offices`, and `/offices`). As far as I understand your server seems to be working fine that `/api/offices` works but `/offices` does not. Or maybe I'm not understanding what `/offices` on the server is meant to server (is it API data or the frontend page?)

Comment: Sure i'll add the code snippets above. /api/offices for fetching the list of offices, and /offices/ for serving the front end page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Express is serving your Vue app statically, you should be using host-relative URLs, eg

```js
axios.get("/api/offices") // DO NOT configure axios.defaults.baseURL
```

Then there's absolutely no reason to allow cross-origin access, making your application simpler and safer overall.

Your entire server configuration should look more like this

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
require('dotenv').config();
const morgan = require('morgan');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const app = express();

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.json());

// Import route modules for each resource
const officesRoutes = require('./routes/officesRoutes');

// API routes should be defined before static file serving
app.use('/api/offices', officesRoutes);

// Serve static files for non-API routes
const frontendDir = path.join(__dirname, '../frontend/dist');
app.use(express.static(frontendDir));

// Client-side routing handler
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  // no need to check the path here
  res.sendFile(path.join(frontendDir, 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

---

You can even run the Vite dev server on its own for local development without changing URLs. Simply configure the [dev server proxy](https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-proxy) to forward `/api` URLs to Express

```js
// vite.config.js

export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': 'http://localhost:3000',
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Ok, I'll make the necessary changes and report back.

Comment: Ok this worked. Although something odd has happened where the issue has now flipped around. I can see my office list in the backend local instance, localhost:3000/offices. But when i try for the same on the front end local:8081/offices, i see a long recursing line of empty list items. Either way, you solved the main issue, so thanks.

Answer (score -2):

It seems that the headers that has been define in the cors are not set in the responses.this issue is in the headers that that has been define in your cors .check that the headers you have define in the cors are being sent in the responses and also check that you are not sending any another header,if you are sending another header then define it in the cors.This will resolve the issue.

Comment: I've checked the headers, but can't see any others that i would need to define with my setup.

At the moment i'm just using JSON data, so content-type should be sufficient.

Do you agree with this assessment?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).